# Insert image in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm trying to insert an image in an email following this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/326346/How-to-embed-a-image-in-email-body
but for some images are not showing in the mail.
Here is the code.

```
var message = new MailMessage();                
message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@happy.com");

message.To.Add("testmail@gmail.com");
var body = new StringBuilder();

message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
var path = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg";
AlternateView altView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("testing mail: <img src=cid:myImage>", null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
LinkedResource imageToSend = new LinkedResource(path);
imageToSend.ContentId = "myImage";

altView.LinkedResources.Add(imageToSend);
message.AlternateViews.Add(altView);


var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Send(message);
```

Comment: By some are not showing in the email, do you mean some of the images, or some of the emails, or certain email clients are showing the images?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Tim images are not showing in thunderbird and in gmail

Comment: Are you adding the contentId into the message as text as well?

Comment: @dotnetrocks - I'd check the documentation for those two clients to see if they allow embedded images or not.  They may not, or it may be an option the user needs to set.